# Which schema for a tour/ travel experience?

Tags: schema, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

I have tour (travel experiences) on my website. I am a bit confised what schema to use for a tour page?

I can see there is `TouristTrip` schema (https://schema.org/TouristTrip) available but strangely it doesn't allow any `aggregateRating` or `review` elements while I want to include them in the tour page schema. The only I can use in this case is `Product` (https://schema.org/Product) but google also demands for this one such properties as `sku` which my tour 'product' does not have.

I probably can use multiple schemas in one page eg. `TouristTrip` and `Review` and `AggregateRating` but they won't be linked between themselves.

Have you had a similar problem and how have you resolved it?

Comment: Do you intend to get a specific rich result in Google Search? If yes, which one?

Comment: Hmm, yes I want to have rating visible in the search results but also would like to qualify it as a trip because I think there are some advantages too

Comment: Can your travel experiences be booked, or is it something like a guide with suggestions what to do?

Comment: They can be booked yes